# Trying to echo a specific variable from a specific row

Tags: php, mysql

So I am attempting to;
-send a HTTP request from another source to the php file, within that http request it will contain something like;  http://mywebsite.com/postServer.php/type=cmd&game=5342252 and what is should be doing is taking the post "game" and comparing it with the table to find witch row contains 5342252 in the column "gid".

However its not working. Now if I remove $game = $_POST["game"] and just put 5342252 were $game is it will work just fine... So im very confused as to why it wont work with $_POST

```
<?php
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $game = $_POST["game"];
     if(type == "cmd") {
      $con = new mysqli("localhost","***","***","***");
     if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo(mysqli_connect_error());
     }
       $data = $con->query("SELECT * FROM onlineservers WHERE gid =".$game);
     while($row = $data->fetch_array()){
       echo json_encode(array('command' => $row[cmd]));
     }
   }

?>
```

Comment: If I remove if(trype == 'cmd') { }

I get the error;
Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

Comment: I have clearly explained your Errors regarding the code and i have given you the solutions for the answer. have a look and share thoughts. if you face any hindrance let me know and we shall solve it.

Comment: I have added a note and modified the code with some more clear explanations. Hope so it would be useful for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: First you must understand how to pass the variables in the URL with parameters. You have been missing the basic knowledge of how to pass the variables as parameters in the URL.

**Rules:**

1. First Parameter to be given with `?` mark  alone with value
2. Second Parameter to be given with `&` symbol along with values.
3. You can add any number of parameter provide the first one has to be with the `?` symbol otherwise the code will not work.

**Example:** `http:// domain.com?first_param=1&second_param=2`

Brief Explanations on URL Parameters.

```
http://domain.net/page.php?id=1254
```

> Why is there a question mark after the page name?

The answer is that the characters after the question mark are an HTTP query string. An HTTP query string can contain both variables and their values. In the example above, the HTTP query string contains a variable named "id", with the value "1254".

Here is another example:

```
http://domain.net/page.php?name=Joe
```

Again, you have a variable ("name") with a value ("Joe").

> How to get the variable with PHP?

Let's say you have a PHP page named people.php. Now you can call this page using the following URL:

```
people.php?name=Joe
```

With PHP, you will be able to get the value of the variable 'name' like this:

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['name']; // Result the Output as Joe
echo $_GET['name']; // Result the Output as Joe
?>
```

Let's try it in an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Query string</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// The value of the variable name is found
echo "<h1>Hello " . $_GET["name"] . "</h1>";

// The value of the variable name is found
echo "<h1>Hello " . $_REQUEST["name"] . "</h1>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

> Several variables in the same URL:

You are not limited to pass only one variable in a URL. By separating the variables with **&**, multiple variables can be passed:

```
people.php?name=Joe&age=24
```

This URL contains two variables: name and age. In the same way as above, you can get the variables like this:

```
$_GET["name"]
$_GET["age"]
```

Let's add the extra variable to the example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Query string </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// The value of the variable name is found
echo "<h1>Hello " . $_GET["name"] . "</h1>";
// The value of the variable age is found
echo "<h1>You are " . $_GET["age"] . " years old </h1>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

## Solution for Your Code

1.) Your URL should be like this as i have stated below.

```
http://mywebsite.com/postServer.php/?type=cmd&game=5342252
```

Then alone you can retrieve the data from the URL separately

2.) In order to get the data from the URL you have to use `$_GET` OR `$_REQUEST`. **But you have used `$_POST` which is totally a blunder**

It should be

```
$type = $_REQUEST["type"];
$game = $_REQUEST["game"];
```

3.) If statement seems to a error in your code.

You have to replace it as this:

```
if($type == "cmd") {}
```

But you have done like this `if(type == "cmd") {}` whoch leads to fatal error.

4.) While selecting the statements you have to check for the count of the query executed since if the count is ZERO and you execute the `while` or `foreach` you may be facing error.
Hence the Entire code will look like as follows:

```
<?php
    $type = $_REQUEST["type"];
    $game = $_REQUEST["game"];
     if($type == "cmd") {
      $con = new mysqli("localhost","***","***","***");
     if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo(mysqli_connect_error());
     }
       $data = $con->query("SELECT * FROM onlineservers WHERE gid =".$game);
       $count = $data->num_rows;
       if($count==0)
       {
        // perform the failure action
       }
       else
       {
       while($row = $data->fetch_array()){
       echo json_encode(array('command' => $row[cmd]));
       }
       }
   }
?>
```

After you have done all the checks that i have mentioned above you have to ensure the note below in order to check your code works or not.

> **Note:** You first put echo to the Select Statement and then break the execution by putting the exit; and you copy the statement that is echoed and place it in SQL of the DB and then check whether any error occurs in insertion. If no error occurs remove the echo and delete the exit;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$type = $_GET["type"];
$game = $_GET["game"];
 if($type == "cmd") {
  $con = new mysqli("localhost","***","***","***");
 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo(mysqli_connect_error());
 }
   $data = $con->query("SELECT * FROM onlineservers WHERE gid =".$game);
 while($row = $data->fetch_array()){
   echo json_encode(array('command' => $row[cmd]));
 }
  }

?>
```

You are not Posting the data, but receiving the data and hence `$_GET` is required.

And also your url shoud be like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/postServer.php?type=cmd&game=5342252
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the php and now im getting the error;
Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

Comment: @ICostaExDesigns Your `$data` variable is returning empty.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$_POST["..."]` for `$_GET["..."]`.

Each variable that you pass in URL is obtained through the $_GET method.

Example: If you do `http://some.com/anything.php?var=test` if you do `$_GET["var"]` you will get "test".